# how to reverse-engineer the C integer type from the assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

Consider the following C function prototype, where `num_t` is a data type declared using typedef:

```
void store_prod(num_t *dest, unsigned x, num_t y) {
 *dest = x*y;
}
```

gcc generates the following assembly code implementing the body of the computation:
What data type is `num_t`?

The correct answer is that `num_t` is `unsigned long long` but I really don't understand why, any help will be greatly appreciated!!

```
# dest  at %ebp +8, x at %ebp +12, y at %ebp +16
movl  12(%ebp), %eax
movl  20(%ebp), %ecx
imull %eax, %ecx
mull  16(%ebp)
leal  (%ecx,%edx), %edx
movl  8(%ebp), %ecx
movl  %eax, (%ecx)
movl  %edx, 4(%ecx)
```

Comment: Was `mull 6(%ebp)` supposed to be `16`?  Otherwise the code makes no sense, because a dword load from `6(%ebp)` would partially overlap the dword at `8(%ebp)`.

Comment: yess, i wrote it wrong, so sorry x) 
it's fixed

Comment: The convention is to return values that don't fit into a single register (AX) via the DX:AX register pair. [but it is  compiler/platform-dependedent]. Also x86 multiplications put the most significant part ofthe result into DX.

Comment: @wildplasser: gcc is computing the value in `edx:eax`, but the function stores the value to memory.  The C return type is `void`.  Perhaps this is un-optimized code; `gcc -O0` seems to treat it almost like a GNU C statement-expression and does reliably make the last assignment work as a return value.  Probably because of some quirk of gcc's internal design.

Comment: Well, snippet stores dx:ax in (cx)+4 and (cx), Could be that x86 still has some *fast path* for this register pair.

Comment: @wildplasser: No, instructions don't run faster on EDX:EAX, but the output of widening [`mul` is implicitly `edx:eax`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MUL).  Only multi-operand forms of `imul` give you a choice.  The compiler had no choice without using extra `mov` instructions (except it used LEA to give itself a choice where to put the upper half, for no reason) .  `mul` and `cdq` are *why* the calling convention made that choice.  (Are you using Go asm notation, where AX actually means EAX or RAX?  This is a 32-bit question using AT&T syntax, so just say EDX:EAX.)

Answer (score 4):

We can tell from the use of `(%ebp)` addressing modes that this is 32-bit code, not x86-64.

In 32-bit mode, `unsigned long long` is the only 64-bit unsigned integer type, in any of the common ABIs.  (e.g. the i386 System V ABI, used on Linux).  `long` is 32-bit.

We can tell that `num_t` is a 64-bit integer type because it's stored in two 32-bit halves from the result of integer multiply and addition.

We can tell that it's an `unsigned` integer type because gcc used `mul` instead of `imul` between the `x` and the low half of `y`.  (2-operand `imul %eax, %ecx` to multiply `x` with the upper half of `y` is the same binary operation for signed or unsigned: only full-multiply (N x N => 2N bits) cares about signedness.)

IDK why gcc would use `leal  (%ecx,%edx), %edx` instead of `add %ecx, %edx`.  Maybe you compiled with `-mtune=atom` or something?  Preserving flags isn't necessary.

Anyway, it's an ordinary 64 x 32 => 64 bit extended-precision multiplication.

---

This is C, not C++, so a class wrapping a 64-bit integer with an overloaded `*` operator can be ruled out, too.

We can rule out FP types because that would have used an FP multiply.